# How to use sample inside ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement

I have following list

```
x = rep("a", 100)
```

and if i used following table

```
ifelse(x == "a", sample(c(1:100), 1), 0)
```

I get following output when I run first time.

```
[1] 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22
[22] 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22
[43] 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22
[64] 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22
[85] 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22
```

I am not able to see random sample between 1 and 100. How should I achieve it. I want randomness in output. Example of expected output is as follows:

```
  [1]   8  81  46  71  97  18  37  82  74  34  12   5  26   6  66  55
 [17]   2  84  68   9  29   7  38   4  64  90  39  54  75  45  20  42
 [33]  79  36  78  13  47  85  27  69  23  62  15  63  76  25  77  96
 [49]  98  11  53  83  30  41  91  43  88  28  65  10  49  99  56  67
 [65]  16  95  32  92  14  86  50  80  94  58  21  87  51  17  70   1
 [81]  33  57  59  73  52  22  31  44 100  61  60  35  89  24  48  72
 [97]  40  19   3  93
```

Comment: Your 'x' is all 'a', why do you need an `ifelse`, instead just do `sample(100)`

Comment: How did you come up with expected output?

Comment: @akrun I think he might just have a bad example. His actual data may not contain all 'a's.

Comment: @parksw3 yes, it could be the case.

Comment: Fyi, in this special case where your alternative value is zero, you can do `(x=="a")*sample(100)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned above your `sample` generate only one number. To fix it your `ifelse` should be looks like this:

```
x = rep("a", 100)
ifelse(x == "a", sample(c(1:100), length(x)), 0)
```

or, if I correctly understand what do you want, even shorter version:

```
x = rep("a", 100)
ifelse(x == "a", sample(length(x)), 0)
```

If you want replace your "not a" value with sampling with replacement (each number can occurs several times) we finally get this code:

```
x = rep(c("a","b"), 50)
ifelse(x == "a", sample(length(x), replace = TRUE), 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect `ifelse` runs `sample()` only once and returns this random value for each element where the condition is TRUE.
You could instead use

```
sapply(x,function(y){
    ifelse(y == "a", sample(c(1:100), 1), 0)
})
```

Comment: Your suspicion is confirmed by `sample(c(1:100), 1)`  The second 1 tells it to run only once

Comment: Of course `sample(c(1:100), 1)` will only return one value. The question here was if `ifelse` will re-run the `sample(c(1:100), 1)` command for each element where condition is TRUE –  seems not to be the case.

Comment: Line 23 in `head(ifelse, 9999)` shows that it is run only once and recycled (replicated).

Comment: Nice one, @RichScriven!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to interpret your question:

```
x <- sample(c("a", "b"), 100, replace = TRUE)
res <- rep(0, length(x))
res[which(x == "a")] <- sample(length(x), sum(x == "a"), rep = TRUE)
```

Looking at `ifelse(x == "a", sample(c(1:100), 1), 0)`, I'm guessing that what you want to do is this:

```
for(i in 1:length(x)){res[i] <- ifelse(x[i] == "a", sample(100, 1), 0)}
```

So it seemed like `rep = TRUE` was necessary. Also, `x == "a"` returns a TRUE/FALSE vector but it can also be converted to numeric vector by `as.numeric(x == "a")` to return 1/0 instead. Using `sum` without `as.numeric` still works and will return a number of elements in `x` that equal `a`.